# NVDA pick changes before react updates the html dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, nvda, jaws-screen-reader

Here I have an component which changes it's data dynamically. And we have a requirement to support both JAWS and NVDA.

When I updated props from the parent component, the relevant component gets updated all the things are working fine for the normal user. But when using the two screen readers NVDA does not pick the change.

Few methods inside the component..

```
render() {
   console.log("render");
   var alertForPrevButton = document.querySelector('#readDesc');

   if (alertForPrevButton !== null) {
       alertForPrevButton.textContent = this.props.messageBody + this.generateMessages();
   }

   return (<div className="messages">
               <div className="sr-only" aria-live="assertive" id="readDesc"></div>
               <p>{this.props.messageBody}</p><p>{this.generateMessages()}</p>
           </div>);
}

generateMessages() {
   console.log("generateMessages");
   const courseEndDate = moment(this.props.courseEndDate);
   var date            = moment(this.props.selectedDate);
   var dayCount        = 0;

   while (courseEndDate.diff(date) >= 0) {
       var assignmentsForDate = AssignmentHelper.getAssignmentsForDueDate(
                                   this.props.allAssignments,
                                   date.format(AppConstants.DATE_FORMAT));

       if (assignmentsForDate.length > 0) {

           switch (dayCount) {
               case 1:
                   return MessageConstants.getFutureDueAssignmentMessage('tomorrow');
               default:
                   return MessageConstants.getFutureDueAssignmentMessage('in ' + dayCount + ' days');
           }

       }

       dayCount += 1;
       date.add(1, 'days');
   }

   return MessageConstants.getNoDueAssignmentMessage();
}
```

Here I have use **aria-live="assertive"**. With that JAWS picks the change and reads accordingly. But NVDA does not pick the change.

does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

WAI-ARIA support is both screen reader and browser dependent, and is average at best. It's almost always better to avoid using ARIA unless it's something you are unable to replicate using native HTML.

In terms of aria-live in NVDA, it hardly works and there is only very basic support for it. NVDA versions 2017.1 to 2017.4 do not read aria-live regions in Firefox, or Chrome. Older versions work in Firefox but not IE.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7906) raised in relation to this on NVDA's git, but it has yet to be resolved.

All in all, it's likely not your code, especially if JAWS is picking it up appropriately.

**Useful WAI-ARIA Compatibility Reference**
[PowerMapper WAI-ARIA Screen Reader Compatibility](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/)